# How to enable/disable displaying of qtip2 tool tips dependent on screen size?

Tags: knockout.js, qtip2

Let's say I want to disable qtip2 tool tips on smaller screen widths.
I would like to accomplish that without using media queries.

I am working with knockoutjs and this is the markup example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="end date" data-bind="qtip2: {config: {content: {text: 'end date tool tip'}, style: {classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'}, position: {my: 'top-right', at: 'bottom-left'}}}" />
```

And this is custom binder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.qtip2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var config = options.config || {};
        $element.qtip(config);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it with help of jQuery:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.qtip2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var config = options.config || {};
        var minWidth = 767;
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowWidth = $window.width();
        if (windowWidth > minWidth)
            $element.qtip(config);
        $window.bind('resize', {$element: $element, $window: $window, minWidth: minWidth}, function() {
            if ($window.width() > minWidth)
                $element.qtip('enable', true);
            else
                $element.qtip('disable', true);
        })
    }
};
```

If qtip('enable', true) and qtip('disable', true) were expensive operations or I had many qtips then fact that there is no check if those functions should really be called (window could be resized but it qtip's enabled state still should not toggled) would be a performance issue.